How can I get AWS Amplify to rebuild when I call a webhook?
I am hosting a Next.JS app on AWS Amplify and I want to trigger a rebuild from my CMS. The Amplify instance is connected to a repository on GitHub.
I followed Creating an incoming webhook to start a build in the AWS docs and got an URL in the form of https://webhooks.amplify.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/webhooks?id=<id>&token=<token>.
When I call this URL, I get the http error code 403 with the response
{"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}

No build is started. How can I set up the webhook properly?
